# Plotly js stacked area with overlapping series

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have data with overlapping dates that I want to visualise in a stacked area graph. So imagine the x-axis with 7 days and three series with the following data:

```
[5, 3, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
[undefined, 2, 4, 2, 2, undefined, undefined],
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3, 3, 5],
```

The numbers indicate the progress made on different projects, and each has a short lifetime, so generally the first number is the date the project was started on. Meaning on the first day, only the first project was active.

However, hovering over any point in the graph shows ALL the projects, both finished and not yet started, with a progress of '0'. In this small example it doesn't really matter, but if I expand the timeframe to a month or a year, it gets fairly crowded.

Further, all the 0 projects are still plotted, leaving an ugly jagged line on top of the graph. Note the line on the extreme right: it includes information that no progress was made on the project that started Jan 19.

[image: A more concrete example]

I think what I want to do is not plot anything where the value is 0/undefined. Is that possible? Is there perhaps a better way of visualising this sort of data?

Here's an example:

[JsFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/csxpnzr5/)

**Update:**

Setting `hoverinfo` to `'text'` and `hovertext` to an array solves the labelling issue. If `hovertext` is a string, it will appear at every point, if it's an array, the first item will only appear on the first node, etc.

See here: [JsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ocyvtj2z/2/)

Comment: Can  you add the code which you are currently using to create the shown graph? A [MCVE] would be great.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Added a fiddle, hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Are you looking for something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/s04jcxb7/

Comment: Almost! Already much better... Just to clarify, the solution is to explicitly set the undefineds to NaN? 

My other issue though is the 1 px wide line that goes across the whole of the graph. Note that the green 'conspiracy' line starts all the way at the start. If you had 20 other things in-between, this becomes clearer, and all the 0 values get overlaid resulting in a jagged line. Is there a way to set the width to 0 where no value is defined? Otherwise I can just set the width to 0 for the whole thing and the problem goes away, just prefer the look when the line is present.

Comment: The "hack" is to define the `text`/`hovertext` for each trace manually and force plotly to use `text` as its `hoverinfo`. Unfortunately I don't have a solution for your problem with line showing up for empty/undefined values. Guess `line: {width: 0}` is your best option here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Feel free to reword the label hack as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Actually, found a much simpler solution. Edited the question accordingly